# Modify,Add,Delete data from XML using as.net controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

My requirement is i have a dropdownlist which has few values from database loaded.
and i have an xml which looks like this

```
<School>
  <Students>
    <Name>Messi</Name>
    <RollNumber>1234</RollNumber>
  </Students>
  <Students>
    <Name>Mario</Name>
    <RollNumber>666</RollNumber>
  </Students>
  <Students>
   <Name>Zlatan</Name>
    <RollNumber>456</RollNumber>
  </Students>
  <Students>
    <Name>Ronaldo</Name>
    <RollNumber>789</RollNumber>
  </Students>
</School>
```

On choosing values from drop down list i have 3 buttons `ADD` `Modify` `Delete`

if the Name in dropdown list present in xmli ll have to enable modify and Delete button 
if the name of the student not present in XML i ll have to enable only Add button

```
ADD
```

-On click of Add button a new row has to be added to the xml-Need code for this

```
Modify
```

-On click of Modify button existing name and rollnumber should be modified in xml by giving a text box to fill new data for roll number only

```
Delete
```

-On click of delete button the row corresponding to the name should be deleted from xml

Please help me with this code

Tools used
1.xml
2.dropdown
3.textbox-for modify
4.buttons
with simple asp controls.

Comment: the code for fetching data from xml i have used like this

Comment: string xmlPath = 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLPath"].ToString();
                    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(xmlPath));
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                string RollNumber =string.Empty;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["Name"].ToString() == ddlApplication.SelectedValue.Trim())
                    {
                        RollNumber = dr["RollNumber "].ToString();
                    }
                }